# C++ Dynamic Memory Allocation. Assigning a Dynamically allocated array of char* return variable to a char variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, char, heap-corruption

So I am trying to add a Dynamically allocated `char*` that is returned from a procedure named

```
GetFileInputFromUser();
```

I dynamically allocate the memory for the return variable inside the procedure.

```
char* pstrReturnValue;

// Prime the loop
cout << "please enter a file location on your local machine (type 1 for default location) ";
cin >> strFileInputFromUser;

// Default location?
if (*(strFileInputFromUser + intIndex) == '1')
{
    // yes, Get the length
    intLength = strlen(strDefaultFileLocation);

    // Allocate memory
    pstrReturnValue = new char[intLength];

    // copy default location in
    for (intIndex = 0; intIndex <= intLength; intIndex += 1)
    {
        *(pstrReturnValue + intIndex) = *(strDefaultFileLocation + intIndex);
    }

return pstrReturnValue;
```

what I need is to add the return variable to another array of chars (Dynamically allocated).

```
void main()
{
bool blnResult = false;
ifstream ifsDataFile;
udtNodeType* pudtHeadNode = 0;
udtNodeType* pudtCurrentNode = 0;
udtNodeType* pudtNextNode = 0;
char* strFile;

udtNodeType udtReturnNode;

// Get the file path
strFile = GetFileInputFromUser();

blnResult = OpenFile(strFile, ifsDataFile);

// was it successful?
if (blnResult == true)
{
    // Yes
    // populate the list and, return the top node
    udtReturnNode = *PopulateList(pudtNextNode, pudtCurrentNode, pudtHeadNode, &ifsDataFile);

    // All done, close the file
    ifsDataFile.close();

    delete[] strFile;

    // Delete the list
    DeleteList(pudtNextNode, pudtCurrentNode, pudtHeadNode);

    // Delete proof
    PrintList(pudtNextNode, pudtCurrentNode, pudtHeadNode);
}

system("pause");
}
```

This is an exercise and as per the requirements, `GetFileInputFromUser()` has to be `char*` it has to return that pointer and I have to delete that pointer before I Dispose the LinkedList. My thing is this, I know how to dynamically allocate memory, and I know how to delete said memory, my problem is I can't just assign a value to a statically allocated `char[]`, I cant loop through the return value to assign it cause I have to be able to get the return vale into something.

I have tried changing `char* GetFileInputFromUser()` to `char& GetFileInputFromUser()` hoping I could get the address at the location in memory, and see if I could hopefully work with it that way be de-referencing the return value somehow.

If you comment out `delete[] strFile` and run it, it runs fine, but I am leaking memory, and that is no good in my eyes. I know there is a way to do this but google isn't helping and I have been stuck on this since 1am last night.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: If you want to use strings, then use `std::string`, then you won't have problems with memory allocations, and you won't have problems writing out of bounds, which you are doing now. You *do* however terminate the string, but (which is what will cause the out of bounds writing) but that's more luck I guess.

Comment: And regarding the leaking, if `OpenFile` fails then you will leak the memory anyway.

Comment: I dont forget to terminate the string, cause when I added the UserInput to the new dynamically allocated char[] I copy over the terminator as well, I just stepped through the debugger to check before I posted this response. I can't use std::String I would love to, but that wont meet the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Askarali you sent me down the right path, the code below is what was needed to get the desired result with out getting a corrupt heap exception. Thank you

```
void main()
{
    char* strFile;

    strFile = new char[50];

    // Get the file path
    strcpy(strFile, GetFileInputFromUser());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add one string to another one. Correct? If so, you could just use **strcat()**.

Comment: will that work for adding a returned char array to another char array?

Comment: char array is pointer to char: **char***. So it should work. **strcat()** has two parameters: **strcat(char *dest, const char *src);**. **src** will be appended to **dest**. So **dest** must have enough size to hold **src** too.

Comment: char* strFile[50];

     strcat(*strFile, GetFileInputFromUser());   I typed it in, doesn't work throws an exception.  *EDIT* if I declare char* strFile; then type strFile = new char[50]; then strcat works, but without the desired results, but if I use strcpy(); I get the results I was looking for I believe.

Comment: It will work if you remove * from `char* strFile[50];`